# How to initi SV queue with binary values

Tags: system-verilog

I have an queue, which I want to init with the binary value. What is the best way to do that?

`logic serial_frame[$];` // Want to init with 0010_0000_1000_0

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

- Array Concatenation: { list of values for each queue element }

  ```
  serial_frame = {0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0, 0}; // first element is serial_frame[0]
  ```
- Bit-stream cast: uses a type to reformat source to target type

  ```
  typedef logic bitstream_t[$];
  serial_frame = bitstream_t'(13'b0010_0000_1000_0);
  ```

  The MSB of the source becomes serial_frame[0]. The size of the target must be adjustable to the size of the target. (not a problem with 1-bit queue, but would be an error if you had a queue of 8-bit bytes)
- Streaming operator (unpack). You can chose the order of the stream

  ```
  {>>{serial_frame}} = 13'b0010_0000_1000_0; // same ordering as bit-stream cast
  {<<{serial_frame}} = 13'b0010_0000_1000_0; // reverse ordering - LSB is serial_frame[0];
  ```

  The streaming operator is probably the easiest for your situation, but be aware that for other target types, it left-justifies data unlike normal assignments which right-justifies data. It also 0-pads data when the source size is smaller than the target.

See sections *10.10 Unpacked array concatenation*, *6.24.3 Bit-stream casting*, and *11.4.14 Streaming operators (pack/unpack)* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).